# Collection list best_in_place in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, best-in-place

i need something similar

```
f.select(:category_id, @categories.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] } + [ [ 'Or create a new one', 'new' ] ], {:include_blank => 'Please select a category'})
```

for the `best_in_place` collection list, for adding values and populating in collection.

Comment: in categories drop down you want to add some more options..right?

Comment: yeah, i need to create one or more values..

Comment: anybody done this before?

Answer (score -1):

Try With

```
<%= f.select :category_id, options_for_select(@categories.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] } + [ [ 'Or create a new one', 'new' ] ]), {:include_blank => 'Please select a category'}, class: "form-control" %>
```